# Set a Firebase Storage file's public filename?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way to control the filename of a Firebase Storage file's public URL?

Pretty typical use case. User's upload files, then other users download/access them at a public URL. The uploading user shouldn't need to worry about filename conflicts, and be able to control the filename when the file is downloaded.

I have a Firestore collection with user defined metadata; name, author, etc. The files themselves are stored in Firebase Storage using the firestore document ids to ensure they're unique and make the link to the firestore document obvious.

I have a firebase http function that allows users to download files from firebase storage:

```js
functions.http.onRequest((req, res) => {
  
  // Get the file id from `req.url`
  // Load the corresponding document from firestore

  let file = getStorage().bucket().file("{file-id}");
  let [doesExist] = await file.exists();
  
  if(doesExist) {
    
    let [isPublic] = await file.isPublic();
    if(!isPublic) {
      await file.makePublic(); // <-- Can I set the filename here?
    }

    let url = file.publicUrl(); // <-- Or here?
    return res.redirect(url);

  }

});
```

This has a couple of problems: The downloaded file doesn't have an extension, so breaks in a lot of cases. And the filename is a document id and not particularly user friendly.

I've thought about piping the file to res with something like:

```js
let fileStream = await file.createReadStream();
fileStream.pipe(res);
```

But I'm worried this would be a whole lot slower, and cost a lot more.

Another consideration is ranged request for video files.

Comment: It will, in fact, be slower and cost more.  But this style of solution is likely your only chance at getting the behavior you want.  I don't think there is any way to alias any content in Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. A storage CDN, with public, sharable, and consistent, URLs, wouldn't be that unusual of a use case. Am I thinking about this all wrong? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Cloud Storage is all those things, and you have to accept the name of the object that you use to store it. If you must absolutely customize the name differently than you stored it, maybe you're looking for a different product.